# Vim and Xdebug issue

Tags: vim, xdebug

Ok so I am having an issue.  I am on an old system ubuntu 9.04 so I don't have the ability to do an apt-get on vim, so I went to the vim site and downloaded the latest version of vim.

Same thing goes for Xdebug, it is all installed and it shows up in the output of my phpinfo() call so that is all good, have the debugger.py and debuger.vim in my /etc/vim/plugin folder, did have it in .vim/plugin but that wasn't working either.

So I run the vim command in my terminal with the file name I want to debug, vim opens it fine but when I open it in the browser and then hit 5 on vim, it doesn't do anything.  No messages what so ever from vim, I added feature&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1 to my url and tried again, still nothing from vim at all, any ideas what the issue could be?

### UPDATE

So I copied these files into /usr/local/vim/vim64/plugin directory since thats where all the plugins seem to be stored on my system and i am now getting this error when starting Vim.  I am using vim 6.4, maybe the this plugin is for an older version?

```
Error detected while processing /usr/local/share/vim/vim64/plugin/debugger.vim:
line    1:
E488: Trailing characters: # -*- c--oding: ko_KR.UTF-8 -*-
line    2:
E488: Trailing characters: # remote PHP debugger : remote debugger interface to DBGp protocol
  1  
line    4:
E488: Trailing characters: # Copyright (c) 2003-2006 ActiveState Software Inc.
  1  
line    6:
E488: Trailing characters: # The MIT License
  1  
line    8:
E488: Trailing characters: # Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
line    9:
E488: Trailing characters: # a copy of this software and associated documentation files
line   10:
E488: Trailing characters: # (the
line   11:
E488: Trailing characters: # including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify,
line   12:
E488: Trailing characters: # merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
line   13:
E488: Trailing characters: # Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished
line   14:
E488: Trailing characters: # to do so, subject to the following conditions:
  1  
line   16:
E488: Trailing characters: # The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
line   17:
E488: Trailing characters: # in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
  1  
line   19:
E488: Trailing characters: # THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED
line   20:
E488: Trailing characters: # OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
line   21:
E488: Trailing characters: # MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
line   22:
E488: Trailing characters: # IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
line   23:
E488: Trailing characters: # CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
line   24:
E488: Trailing characters: # TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
line   25:
E488: Trailing characters: # SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
  1  
  1  
line   28:
E488: Trailing characters: # Authors:
line   29:
E488: Trailing characters: #    Seung Woo Shin <segv <at> sayclub.com>
line   30:
E488: Trailing characters: #    Sam Ghods <sam <at> box.net>
line   33:    
E492: Not an editor command: ^Idebugger.py -- DBGp client: a remote debugger interface to DBGp protocol
line   35:
E492: Not an editor command:     Usage:
line   36:
E492: Not an editor command:         Use with the debugger.vim vim plugin
line   38:
E492: Not an editor command:     This debugger is designed to be used with debugger.vim,
line   39:
E488: Trailing characters: ^Ia vim plugin which provides a full debugging enviroVim:     Caught deadly signal SEGV

Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your old Vim 6.4 is *sourcing* the `plugin/debugger.py` file, as it complains about the Python `#` comments, instead of feeding this to the Python interpreter. The [XDebug plugin page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4074) lists the minimum required Vim version as 7.0; if that is right, you probably have to upgrade your Vim version (which would be beneficial for many other reasons, too, and compiling your own Vim version isn't so difficult on Ubuntu), or heavily hack the plugin (e.g. try moving the `debugger.py` file elsewhere and adapt the paths in `debugger.vim`).

Comment: Thanks!  I just grabbed the latest version of Vim from their website, now all the errors are gone but when I open the file with Vim and hit f5 nothing at all happens.  I am trying this process with a fresh install of a newer version of Ubuntu to see if I can get it to work there first.